# Nominal vs short circuit test current of transformer

Tags: transformer

Is there a relationship between the short circuit test and nominal current of a single phase transformer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is there a relationship between the short circuit test and nominal
> current of a single phase transformer?*

When you do a short circuit test (shorting the secondary via an ammeter), you adjust the primary voltage (via a variac) to a low enough value so that the nominal current measured on the secondary is achieved.

Hence, nominal (or full-load) current and, a transformer short circuit test have a relationship.